# Determine $\sum_{i=0}^n \frac{(i^2 - 1)}{6} $

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

I have an exercise that requires to determine the sum below and then prove that by induction, but the problem is the first part,
How can I determine this in function of n?
$$\sum_{i=0}^n \frac{(i^2 - 1)}{6}  $$

I tried to substitute $i$ with $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ to get $\frac{n^2+n-2}{12}$ but I'm not quite sure it's right.

Comment: Try to write out the first few terms and see if you can spot a pattern

Comment: Hint: it may be helpful to look at the sum $\sum_{i=2}^n{i\choose2}=\sum_{i=2}^n i(i-1)/2$.

Comment: The $i$ there is a changing constant $ i = 0, \dots n$, but $n$ is the variable that determines the function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\begin{align}&\sum_{i=0}^n\frac{i^2-1}{6} = \frac 16\left[\sum_{i=0}^n i^2 -\sum_{i=0}^n1\right] = \frac16\left[\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6} -(n+1)\right]\end{align}$$

Comment: Why the sum of 1?

Comment: Each time you have $1$, so you have to add that from $i = 0$ to $i = n$, i.e, $n+1$ times.

Comment: Oh ok, I got it!

Answer (score 1):

The main deal is with the $\sum_{i=1}^n i^2$ summation. For calculating it, use the following telescopic series
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n(i+1)^3-i^3=\sum_{i=1}^n3i^2+3i+1=3(\sum_{i=1}^ni^2)+3(\sum_{i=1}^ni)+\sum_{i=1}^n1=(n+1)^3-1
$$
where the $\sum_{i=1}^ni$ and $\sum_{i=1}^n1$ summations are obvious.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by proving this sum by induction, but it's simple enough to evaluate. Note that the summation is a linear operation so can be expanded into separate terms:

$$\sum_{i=0}^n \frac{i^2 - 1}{6} = \frac16 \left[ \sum_{i=0}^n i^2 - \sum_{i=0}^n 1 \right] = \frac16 \left[\frac{2n^3 + 3n^2 + n}{6} - (n + 1)\right] = \frac{2n^3 + 3n^2 - 5n - 6}{36}$$

The sum $\sum_{i=0}^n i^2$ has a standard formula, please see [this Wikipedia article on Square pyramidal numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_pyramidal_number).

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  Easy with the fact that $\sum_{i=0}^ni^2=n (n+1)(2n+1)/6$, which can be proven by induction.